# Set font family and size of equations in flextable

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I'm looking for an option to set the the font family and size of equations in a `flextable`.

In general the font family and size of the table, rows and columns could be set via the sugar functions `flextable::font` and `flextable::fontsize`. However, both have no effect on the font family and size of equations neither in the HTML output nor when exporting to docx.

Running the reprex below gives the correct font family and size for the *text* column but not for the *formula* column.

```r
library(flextable)

# Note: Running the reprex requires the `equatags` package. 
# Also equatags::mathjax_install() must be executed
# to install necessary dependencies. See ?flextable::as_equation.

eqs <- c(
  "(ax^2 + bx + c = 0)",
  "a \\ne 0",
  "x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}"
)
text = LETTERS[1:3]
df <- data.frame(text = text, formula = eqs)
df
#>   text                                 formula
#> 1    A                     (ax^2 + bx + c = 0)
#> 2    B                                a \\ne 0
#> 3    C x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}

ft <- flextable(df)
ft <- compose(
  x = ft, j = "formula",
  value = as_paragraph(as_equation(formula, width = 2))
)
ft <- width(ft, j = 2, width = 2)
ft <- fontsize(ft, size = 20, part = "all")

fn <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")
save_as_docx(ft, path = fn)
if (FALSE) fs::file_show(fn) # Set to TRUE to show file
```

Comment: Did you try running this example: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/as_equation.html?

Comment: @Quinten Yeah. Of course. My reprex is based on that. I also tried with different `width` and `height` arguments as according to the docs these could be used to set the `size of the resulting equation`. But had no luck. Actually I don't understand how these arguments work as these had no effect on the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control the row heights, you need to specify `hrule(ft, i = 1:3, rule = 'atleast')` as well as the height in inches via `height_all`

```r
ft <- flextable(df)
ft <- compose(
  x = ft, j = "formula",
  value = as_paragraph(as_equation(formula, width = 3, height = 2))
)
ft <- width(ft, j = 1:2, width = 2)
ft <- hrule(ft, i = 1:3, rule = 'atleast')
ft <- height_all(ft, height = 1)
ft <- fontsize(ft, size = 20, part = "all")
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't change the size of the equations:

[image]

The mathjax formulas that make up your second column (including the text characters) are rendered as SVG paths, and both their size and font family are fixed.

If you dig into the flextable code you will see that when you do

1. `print(ft)` it calls
2. `flextable:::print.flextable` which calls
3. `htmltools_value(ft)` , which calls
4. `flextable:::html_str(ft)`, which calls
5. `flextable:::html_gen(ft)`, which generates the actual html.

The formula strings are passed directly inside `html_gen` to `equatags::transform_mathjax`, which doesn't take any size or font family parameters, and just spits out default mathjax svg. The svg images are incorporated into the table cells at a fixed size.

In order to change the size of the svgs, you would need to get involved in svg hacking, which in the case of simple scaling isn't too difficult:

```r
html_format <- as.character(htmltools_value(ft))
html_format <- gsub('<svg ',
                    '<svg transform=\"scale(2)\" ',
                    html_format, fixed = TRUE)
```

The `html_format` object is just the html string of the flextable and can be rendered
like this:

```r
dir <- tempfile()
dir.create(dir)
htmlFile <- file.path(dir, "index.html")
writeLines(html_format, con = htmlFile)
rstudioapi::viewer(htmlFile)
```

Resulting in

[image]

None of this is ideal, or course, but it just a limitation of how flextable renders formulas though equatags.

Unfortunately, Mathjax [does not allow for arbitrary fonts to be used](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/font-support.html), so that would be even harder to achieve.

Comment: Hej Allan. Thanks a lot for digging into the source code and showing me how to set the cell heights. More than I expected. Switching the font family is actually not that important for me. More important would be to set the font size in case of docx export (sigh. Working for an Office-centric company.). But for my present use case it's only one table with three equations. So it's okay to do that manually in Word. After digging a bit into the officer source code and OOXML lately I would guess that this should somehow be possible. Will have a look. Best S.

Comment: Hi, equatags will be refactored this year, I just don't have time to focus on that for now. I hope by using katex to get something better